# The default python 2.6.6 not visible in /usr/lib and not able to set virtualenv for it

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv, python-2.6

I have installed 3 python **python 2.7.11 ,python 3 and python 2.6.6**

Previously the default python was **2.7.11**  but after installing the python version 2.6.6 which I installed downloading the zipped file the default became the 2.6.6 one. Which appears when I type python on terminal

Problem:
As the python version 2.6.6 is not shown in /usr/lib I am not able to setup virtualenv for this version of python. with

```
virtual -p path-to-pythonversion
```

but that is possible for 2.7 and 3 as they exist in lib path.

**I also tried without using -p considering will take the default being used but its not working when I install the virtualenv** but doing so its using the python version **python 2.7.11**

Answer (score 1):

Try using this to look for your different python binary or executable that are installed:

```
find /usr/bin -type f -iname "*python*"
```

Verify that the python lib directory does not exist with:

```
find /usr/lib -type d -maxdepth 2 -iname "*python*"
```

I think you may ultimately need some sort of command such as:

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.6
```

What operating system are you using?

Post the output of these commands:

```
which python
ls -l /usr/bin | grep -i python
test -L $(which python)
echo $?
```

Comment: Tried all python 2.6.6 is not shown in thepath but appears as default when typed python on terminal. Is it like the default one is not shown in the path. How do i create a virtualenv for it such case